# Javascript Issue with IE 7 + 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

So I've been trying to get this script working in IE 7 & 8. The lack of support for getElementsByClassName was difficult to say the least, but i have filled support for that with a jQuery library.

My issue here is that the code shows no errors in any browser, yet the code does not run properly in IE. I've tested this in FF, Chrome, and Safari. All other browsers work fine, excluding IE.

I know semantics wise the code could be smaller (Trust me when  get it working i will fix that.) But for now i need to figure out what is holding up IE.

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var forms = jQuery('.form_item');
    var firstFader = forms[4].getElementsByTagName('input');
    var secondFader = forms[6].getElementsByTagName('input'); 

    jQuery(firstFader[0]).click(function() {
      jQuery('#nearSighted').hide('slow');
      jQuery('#farSighted').show('slow');
      jQuery('#astigmatism').hide('slow');
    });

    jQuery(firstFader[1]).click(function() {
      jQuery('#nearSighted').show('slow');
      jQuery('#farSighted').hide('slow');
      jQuery('#astigmatism').hide('slow');
    });

    jQuery(firstFader[2]).click(function() {
      jQuery('#nearSighted').hide('slow');
      jQuery('#farSighted').hide('slow');
      jQuery('#astigmatism').show('slow');
    });

    jQuery(secondFader[2]).click(function() {
      jQuery('#presbyopia').show('slow');
      jQuery('#cataracts').hide('slow');
    });  

    jQuery(secondFader[3]).click(function() {
      jQuery('#presbyopia').hide('slow');
      jQuery('#cataracts').show('slow');
    }); 
  });
```

What this code does is take an array of all form items, then breaks two specific ones down into their individual input elements, when one of the elements is clicked it hides or shows a div that contains information about that specific condition. Any ideas?

Comment: What **exactly** doesn't work in IE?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using jQuery to define the variables "firstFader" and "secondFader"?

Comment: I think any insight is going to require enough of the corresponding HTML to make a running version in IE to see what's going on there.

Comment: Pointy, in IE when the specific inputs are clicked nothing happens, pry shod have mentioned that. You can see a working example here: http://bouldereyes.com/self-evaluation click on the first set of radios, and you can see the desired effect, songless, the only reason i'm using jquery right now is it fill the support gap for getElementsByClassName, i've been having problems with the filler scripts that are supposed to add this functionality to IE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your click handlers aren't being called because your `<input>`s are styled `display:none`, i.e. they're hidden. Modern browsers are lenient because they see a `<label for="id">` so they fire the click event as though it were the input itself (see http://jsfiddle.net/MMUyA/).

Comment: So I've gone ahead and done this, and the code semi works now, however it seems to have trouble showing the right div in IE? I have 2 labels displaying the same text now, the first one displays the correct div, but the 2nd and 3rd ones only display the last div?

Comment: @Xenology, that looks like a problem in all browsers, it looks like a simple mistake in the order of your `.show()` and `.hide()` calls.

Comment: Awesome, good to know, i'll take a look when i get back to the code!

Answer (score 0):

```
var firstFader = forms[4].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
var secondFader = forms[6].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
```

Comment: Wouldn't that just set first/secondFader as the first input in the group? I need it to be set up so when individual inputs are clicked different messages are shown. adding the [0] would set it as the first input all the time, and would cause the code to fail when it tried to find the next index of that variable, I.E. firstFader[1] would be forms[4].getElementsByTagName('input')[0][1]?

Answer (score 0):

I see you're not actually clicking the `input` elements, but the `label` elements for those inputs.

It seems IE doesn't properly propagate the click event to the hidden input, therefor your `.click()` event never gets executed.

See also: [IE - hidden radio button not checked when the corresponding label is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252690/ie-hidden-radio-button-not-checked-when-the-corresponding-label-is-clicked)

The simple solution would to not bind the `click()` events to the `input` but to the `label` instead.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like in IE7, the radio button input object has zero size and the label for it is what actually receives the click and displays the radio button.  Perhaps you need to intercept clicks on the associated label in addition to the input field.