# jQuery and IE: Checking for hidden inputs "checked"-attribute does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, hidden, checked

I've been trying to check if my input[type=hidden] has an checked="checked" attribute.
That input field looks like this:

```
<input type="hidden" checked="checked" name="1_WILLINFOS">
```

In Firefox it works just fine by using:

```
jQuery(selector).find('input[name=1_WILLINFOS]').attr('checked') == "checked"
```

But IE10 always gives me a false.

By now I tried to use the following:

```
.attr("checked") == "checked"
.attr("checked") == true
.is(':checked')
```

With all of them giving me a false.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252690/ie-hidden-radio-button-not-checked-when-the-corresponding-label-is-clicked

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't have hidden input be a checkbox, so it won't have a `checked` property. You can use a `type="checkbox"` and hide it with `display:none` if you need it to be a checkbox, or you can simply use the hidden input with a `0` or a `1` instead to kind of simulate it.

Answer (score 3):

You can have hidden element with any attribute .
E.g

```
<input type="hidden" abc="xyz" name="1_WILLINFOS">//is an `input` type `hidden` with attribute abc having value xyz
```

In Your case,

```
<input type="hidden" checked="checked" name="1_WILLINFOS">//is an `input` type `hidden` with `attribute` checked with value `checked`


$('input[name=1_WILLINFOS]').attr('checked') == "checked" //is an element with name '1_WILLINFOS' and attribute checked set to 'checked' .So it will surely match and return true
```

but,

```
.attr("checked") == true //will fail as you set `checked` attribute value to 'checked' and your are checked for true condition.so you must check for `.attr("checked") == 'checked`

$('input[name=1_WILLINFOS]').is(':checked'));// will check for attribute checked if its set it will return you true.
```

Here is working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dipak1991/JbqMZ/2/) for you