# check the 'checked' value of all children hidden inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**ANSWER**
[stackoverflow.com/a/18676076/2240163](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18676076/2240163)

> You can't have hidden input be a checkbox, so it won't have a checked
>   property. You can use a type="checkbox" and hide it with display:none
>   if you need it to be a checkbox, or you can simply use the hidden
>   input with a 0 or a 1 instead to kind of simulate it.

I have a container with hidden fields to hold data.

```
    <Panel id="jointlist">
      <input type="hidden" id="jl_C_Head_back_conf" name="C_Head_back_conf" data-location="Head, back"/>
      <input type="hidden" id="jl_C_Head_back_text" name="C_Head_back_text"/>
      <input type="hidden" id="jl_C_Head_front_conf" name="C_Head_front_conf" data-location="Head, front"/>
      <input type="hidden" id="jl_C_Head_front_text" name="C_Head_front_text"/>
    </Panel>
```

Im trying to find which input elements has a `checked` value of true.

Ive tried

```
var jointlist = $("#jointlist");
var items = jointlist.find("input[id*='_conf']:checked");
```

but this returns the parent node with all the inputs listed under `children`. The item in the pic is true and there is one more true item, but the rest of the 132 remaining items are all false. 
[image]

so then I tried to loop through all the children to find the checked elements, so I tried

```
    jointlist.each(function () {
        var curItem = $(this);
        var chldrn = curItem[0].children;
        for (i = 0; i < chldrn.length; i++) {
            console.log(chldrn[i].checked);
        }
    });
```

This returns the `HTML` of the child element. 
So Im not sure how to access the `checked` attribute of the children.

**EDIT**
This is the screenshot of the for loop `console.log(chldrn[i].checked);`

[image]

Comment: You are not looking at `length` property see its __0__ and hidden element doesn't work with [`:checked` selector](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) so its returning correct

Comment: where is the checkbox(s)? it type="hidden" not type="checkbox"

Comment: Also you're try to get ':checked' but there is no elements

Comment: Why is the length 0 if there are items with checked values of true. Im lost here

Comment: There are no checkboxes. its hidden inputs with a checked value of true.

Comment: The object's length in debugger console is 0, and why are you navigate into the `prevObject`?

Comment: @Alessandro - sorry but what do you mean by why are you navigate into prevObject. I just console.log the variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch all the input elements first:

```
var inputs = document.getElementById('jointlist').getElementsByTagName('input');
```

then loop through and get the checked value like

```
inputs[i].getAttribute('checked');
```

```js
var inputs = document.getElementById('jointlist').getElementsByTagName('input');
var res;
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  if (inputs[i].getAttribute('checked') === 'true') {
    res = inputs[i];
  }
} 
console.log(res);
```

```html
<Panel id="jointlist">
    <input type="hidden" id="jl_C_Head_back_conf" name="C_Head_back_conf" data-location="Head, back" checked="true" />
    <input type="hidden" id="jl_C_Head_back_text" name="C_Head_back_text"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="jl_C_Head_front_conf" name="C_Head_front_conf" data-location="Head, front"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="jl_C_Head_front_text" name="C_Head_front_text"/>
</Panel>
```

Comment: Sorry, but look at the last screenshot I added. I get the same window when I log `inputs`. and then a 134 Undefined values when I lof `inputs[i].attributes.checked`

Comment: Seems like is is not possible like this. see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18676076/2240163

Comment: so I created a work around. I added a data attribute of "check". and I base the `checked` on that